# Grid layout issue with Fabric.js 1.4.0 version

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am working on Fabric.js-based project. I am facing problem with Fabric.js 1.4.0 version for grid layout with I Text property 1.4.0 js not apply the grid property properly. but when I am use the Fabric.js 1.3.0 version with simple Text property grid layout working perfectly.

Bellow is the screen shot and link details when working with Fabric.js 1.3.0 & Text property.You can see here all the grid layout is perfect.

[image: grid layout working here]

Bellow is the screen shot and link details when working with Fabric.js 1.4.0  & IText property.You can see here all the grid layout is wrong layout.

[image: grid layout wrong here]

**Bellow is my grid layout function code for both fabricjs versions.( 1.3.0 and 1.4.0)**

```
 document.getElementById('grid').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     //alert("grid");
 //$("#grid").click(function() {
   var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
//alert(width);
//alert(height);
var j = 0;
var line = null;
var rect = [];
var size = 20;
console.log(width + ":" + height);
 for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(width / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = i * size;
    rect[1] = 0;
    rect[2] = i * size;
    rect[3] = height;
    line = null;

    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
      line.selectable = false;
      canvas.add(line);
       line.sendToBack();
        }
for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil(height / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = 0;
    rect[1] = i * size;
    rect[2] = width;
    rect[3] = i * size;
    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    line.selectable = false;
  canvas.add(line);
    line.sendToBack();
   }
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Change originX/originY of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer if you are using grid with fabricjs 1.4.0.

```
document.getElementById('grid').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     //alert("grid");
 //$("#grid").click(function() {
   var width = canvas.width ;
var height = canvas.height ;
//alert(width);
//alert(height);
var j = 0;
var line = null;
var rect = [];
var size = 20;
console.log(width + ":" + height);
 for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(width / 20); ++i ) {
    // alert(i);
    rect[0] = i * size;
    rect[1] = 0;
    rect[2] = i * size;
    rect[3] = height;


    line = null;

    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5,
         top: 0



    });
      line.selectable = false;
      canvas.add(line);
       line.sendToBack();
        }
for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil(height / 20); ++i ) {
    //alert(i);
    rect[0] = 0;
    rect[1] = i * size;
    rect[2] = width;
    rect[3] = i * size;


    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5,
        left:0,

        });
    line.selectable = false;
  canvas.add(line);
    line.sendToBack();
   }
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```